# Word/name for someone who uses/mistreats his subordinates but is loved by his superiors

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word/name for someone who uses/mistreats his subordinates but is loved by his superiors?

I've heard there may be a military-specific name for it.

Answer (score 0):

Concentrating on the treatment of subordinates, a harsh disciplinarian may be called a Martinet, after ["one of the first great drill-masters of modern times" (Wikipedia)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Martinet). A many-tailed whip shares his name.

Martinet himself would presumably have been popular with his commanders, as he was renowned for producing an effective fighting force, but modern use doesn't focus on this.

Comment: *drill master* That makes me think of "drill sergeant" which may also be the the military-related word OP is looking for

Answer (score 0):

An *authoritarian*, perhaps?

There are words that describe one side of the relationship, like *bootlick* for someone who is liked by and pliant toward his superiors, and *bully* for someone who is disliked by and exploitative towards subordinates, but the combination of both tends to suggest an authoritarian actor.